# Como acessar uma Rota de um projeto (URL) escrito em Laravel de um outro projeto (URL) que não usa Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-rotas

Digamos que eu tenha `myApp1.com` e `myApp2.com`, e que somente o segundo projeto está escrito em Laravel.

A minha pergunta é:

Levando em consideração que `myApp2.com` possui autenticação de login, seria possível criar um link em `myApp1.com` que iria direcionar para uma rota em `myApp2.com` ?

```
//myApp1.com
<a href="http://myApp2.com/fazerAlgo/">Faça algo em myApp2.com</a>

//myApp2.com
Route::get('/fazerAlgo', 'outConttroler@fazerendoAlgo')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completamente,

Ficaria assim:

**myApp1.com**

```
<a href="http://myApp2.com/do-something/">Faça algo em myApp2.com</a>
```

**myApp2.com**
*Route*

```
 Route::get('do-something', 'DoSomethingController@do_something');
```

*Controller*

```
public function do_something()
{
    echo "Hello World";
}
```

Acabei de testar funcionou perfeito aqui.
OBS: É claro que sua sessão de autenticação não seria passada para o **myApp2.com**

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: ok... se vc já testou então está beleza. Mas não parece estranho?  De que serve então os filtros de autentição? Como o laravel permite isso? Entáo poderíamos criar um form em um outro servidor para ter acesso a controllers dentro do myApp2.com?

Comment: Por isso você deve usar token nos formulários, para evitar esse tipo de acesso indesejado.

Comment: Veja aqui https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#form-method-spoofing